$3$-SAT $\leq$ IND-SET reduction
How to apply the $3$-SAT $\leq$ IND-SET reduction to the following $3$-SAT for a system of conditions:

$F_{1} = \neg x_1 \vee x2 \vee x3$;
$F_2 = \neg x_2 \vee x_3 \vee x_4$;
$F_3 = \neg x_3 \vee x_4 \vee x_5$;
$F_4 = x_2 \vee \neg x_4$;
$F_5 = x_3 \vee \neg x_5$;

Could anyone explain what I'm supposed to do and how to apply reduction for a given system?
